# Imperfections in Andale Mono font in fbterm

Tags: arch-linux, fonts

Recently I installed the Andale Mono font from the `ttf-ms-fonts` package on Arch Linux AUR.

I then tried out using it in Fbterm to see how it works. It worked perfectly! Well, sort of.

[image: the imperfections]

You can see some of the imperfections in the text I typed into `nano`. You can also see it in the word "GNU" in "GNU nano". Other keys affected included 'y' and others.

Is this a rendering issue, or is it a problem with the font being installed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The former - fbterm is drawing scalable fonts on a low-resolution device, for speed.  You could file a bug report, but see these 2-3  year-old issues:

- [fbterm - issue #64: Fonts have incorrect alignment and spacing in fbterm](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbterm/issues/64)
- [fbterm - issue #70](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbterm/issues/70)

and it seems that there's no ongoing development, just a few people with copies on github.  Followup comments for [Use console fonts with fbterm #47](https://github.com/MItsutoshiNAKANO/fbterm/issues/47) indicate the sort of problems encountered in adapting TrueType fonts to work in the Linux console.